# Default Java library path?

Tags: java, java.library.path

I understand that you can set the Java library path with an option (`-Djava.library.path=/path/to/libs`) before executing the program, but is there a place on the system where Java looks if you don't set it manually?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Its default value depends on the operating system:

- On Windows, it maps to `PATH`
- On Linux, it maps to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- On OS X, it maps to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Where does this infomation come from?

Comment: Good question, no idea.

Comment: The default value is set by [a native method in `System.java`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/System.java.html#521) and I don't have time to dig further into it atm.

Answer (score 12):

However, Matt Ball is not totally correct.

On my Linux box, my Java library path is

```
/usr/lib64/icedtea6/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib64/icedtea6/jre/lib/amd6ib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

While my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is `/usr/local/lib64`.

Comment: Sun / Oracle changed the behavior between 1.6 and 1.7: https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/purging_ld_library_path

Answer (score 12):

For Java 8, this differs based on OS. This is the behavior I observed:

- Windows 10/Oracle JDK 8: `java.library.path=%PATH%;.`
- macOS El Capitan/Oracle JDK 8: `java.library.path=$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH:~/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.`. `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables are ignored. Moreover, both these variables are removed from the environment of Java applications.
- Linux CentOS 7/Open JDK 8: `java.library.path=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib`

Comment: Apparently JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH still works with El Captain and jdk 8, or at least with the recent 1.8.0_162-b12 build