# Referenced Library in Java Project only finds native dll when I specify where they are in IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, dll

I have a library in eclipse that uses native libraries (two dll). The dlls are in the same folder as the jar. When I run the application there is an error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xx in java.library.path
```

When I link the library by double click on native library location, then running it works. However, I don't want to have to do this, I want it to work with out having to configure it via the IDE. I want the library to be plug and play.

Q1: Where is the convetional location to put .dll referenced by a .jar library.

Q2: How can I make sure when someone references my library in eclipse it works without further IDE configuration?

[image: eclipse view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error explains it clearly that your native libraries are not in the default location of `java.library.path`

You just have to set property `java.library.path` to the folder where all native libraries are stored. You can do this by giving argument in the command line `-Djava.library.path=C:/nativeLibs/`

OR

Copy your libraries to default location of `java.library.path`

Refer [Default Java library path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038789/default-java-library-path]) for default location of `java.library.path`